# color warning and error messages gcc ouput with csh?

Tags: csh

After a deep search I could not find any easy way to color the 'warning' and 'error' messages of the gcc output.

In bash we usually add this in .bashrc:

```
 export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

But csh don't allow it. I tried (in .cshrc) :

```
 set GCC_COLORS = 'error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

It does not work. Another constraint is that I cannot really install a program on my machine because I am not root (can't put anything in /bin). Of course, I can put a program in my /home and add something to PATH but I prefer not.

Comment: From a quick search it looks like the csh command is `setenv`, as in `setenv GCC_COLORS 'error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'`.

Comment: @melpomene thx but it does not work. I really wonder where/when the GCC_COLORS variable is set !?

Comment: @melpomene any other ideas ?

Comment: "*It does not work*" is not a problem description.

Comment: 1) I want to color warning and error of gcc output using csh. 2) I tried set the variable exactly like you said. 3) Outputs of warning and errors are still not colored. Have anyone got any other ideas to make the ouputs of errors and warning of gcc colored with csh ? ... I hope it is more clear for you...

Comment: Did you verify that the variable exists in the environment? I don't see `GCC_COLORS` in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html. How do you know this variable is supposed to work?

Comment: Addendum: Never mind the last question; I found it at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html.